# C# Function that tries to find the number that appears the most in an array won't work

Tags: c#, arrays, function, for-loop

Ok, so I'm trying to make a function that will look at an array of numbers and return the digit that appears the most. I tried doing this by setting up counters and a for loop but every time I run it it always returns the value 9, even if it isn't there.

```
public static int ModalNumber(int[] numbers)
{
int ones = 0;
int twos = 0;
int threes = 0;
int fours = 0;
int fives = 0;
int sixes = 0;
int sevens = 0;
int eights = 0;
int nines = 0;
int zeroes = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    if (numbers[i] == 0)
      {
        zeroes++;
      }
    else if (numbers[i] == 1)
      {
        ones++;
      }
    else if (numbers[i] == 2)
      {
        twos++;
      }
    else if (numbers[i] == 3)
      {
        threes++;
      }
    else if (numbers[i] == 4)
      {
        fours++;
      }
    else if (numbers[i] == 5)
      {
        fives++;
      }
    else if (numbers[i] == 6)
      {
        sixes++;
      }
    else if (numbers[i] == 7)
      {
        sevens++;
      }
    else if (numbers[i] == 8)
      {
        eights++;
      }
    else if (numbers[i] == 1)
      {
        nines++;
      }
  }
  if (Convert.ToBoolean(zeroes >> ones & twos & threes & fours & fives & sixes & sevens & eights & nines))
    {
      return 0;
    }
  else if (Convert.ToBoolean(ones >> zeroes & twos & threes & fours & fives & sixes & sevens & eights & nines))
    {
      return 1;
    }
  else if (Convert.ToBoolean(twos >> zeroes & ones & threes & fours & fives & sixes & sevens & eights & nines))
    {
      return 2;
    }
  else if (Convert.ToBoolean(threes >> zeroes & ones & twos & fours & fives & sixes & sevens & eights & nines))
    {
      return 3;
    }
  else if (Convert.ToBoolean(fours >> zeroes & ones & twos & fours & fives & sixes & sevens & eights & nines))
    {
      return 4;
    }
  else if (Convert.ToBoolean(fives >> zeroes & ones & twos & threes & fours & sixes & sevens & eights & nines))
    {
      return 5;
    }
  else if (Convert.ToBoolean(sixes >> zeroes & ones & twos & threes & fours & fives & sevens & eights & nines))
    {
      return 6;
    }
  else if (Convert.ToBoolean(sevens >> zeroes & ones & twos & threes & fours & fives & sevens & eights & nines))
    {
      return 7;
    }
  else if (Convert.ToBoolean(eights >> zeroes & ones & twos & threes & fours & fives & sixes & sevens & nines))
    {
      return 8;
    }
  else
    {
      return 9;
    }
```

I'm sorry in advance for how freakishly long this is, but basically the function uses an array of numbers that is inputted by whoever's using the program - I know this isn't the problem because I wrote some code that displays it while the program runs. Can anyone suggest a way that'd work or would be more efficient? Thanks

Comment: I downvoted this because it's caused by a simple typo.

Comment: `if (numbers[i] == 1) { nines++; }` - `1` is not pronounced `nine`. Also I suggest using an array instead of 10 variables.

Comment: Moreover, `>>` and `&` are not used like that. Check out some C# tutorials.

Comment: You assume the array size is always 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, this is how I would do it (I am not going to give you the code, since it is clearly homework):

- Create an array for the number of possible entries (so an `int[10]` when there are ten possibilities). A better option would be a dictionary to store the count, but we will do the easy way now.
- For each number, increment the number in the just created array for the value (so set array[9] if you want to increment the number of found items for value 9).
- Iterate over the array, and remember the index you found the highest number. You have to store that highest number too as a reference point for your next check.

Answer (score 4):

This should work using LINQ to select the number that appears most frequently in the array:

```
numbers.GroupBy(i => i).OrderByDescending(group => group.Count()).First().Key;
```

When working with arrays, lists, or sequences, I would suggest trying to think about what you need to do in terms of set-based operations, as it often simplifies the solution.  In this case, you need to associate the distinct values in the array with the number of times they occur, and then take the one with the maximum occurrences.  This can be done by grouping the set of integers on their identity (`GroupBy(i => i)`), then counting the number of occurences in each group (`group => group.Count()`), ordering them descending by the count, and taking the first element.

Just in case, since you actually said "return the digit that appears the most", if you actually want the digit and not the number that appears most frequently, you can change the solution accordingly:

```
numbers.SelectMany(i => i.ToString().Select(c => Int32.Parse(c.ToString())))
    .GroupBy(i => i).OrderByDescending(group => group.Count())
    .First()
    .Key;
```

Comment: Not really appropriate for homework, but it will do the job indeed :).

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek -- Actually, it will only work on data types that implement `IEquatable<T>` or work with `ObjectEqualityComparer<T>`, in order to group the elements correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't want to do your homework for you but I already had this

```
static int Most(int[] numbers)
{
    int[] count = new int[10];
    foreach (int n in numbers)
    {
        if (n > 9 || n < 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        count[n]++;
    }
    int max = count[0];
    int maxP = 0;
    for(int p = 1; p < 10; p++)
    {                
        if (count[p] > max)
        {
            max = count[p];
            maxP = p;
        }
    }
    return maxP;
}
```